# 'int' object has no attribute '__getitem__' on a non-integer object

Tags: python

In looking at other answers to this issue I found that the object was usually an integer so i constructed a simple example showing it is not and integer (or so I think), **this code:**

```
import numpy as np
a=np.arange(2,10)
print '1: ', a
print '2: ', a.size
print '3: ', a[3:] #this shows this is not an integer
print '3a: ', len(a[3:]) #len works
print '4: ', a.size[3:] #but yet size does not work
```

**yields:** ============

```
1:  [2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9]

2:  8

3:  [5 6 7 8 9]

4: 
------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-12-5c4b06ceceba> in <module>()

  4 print '2: ', a.size

  5 print '3: ', a[3:] *#this shows this is not an integer*

----> 6 print '4: ', a.size[3:] *#but yet size does not work*

TypeError: 'int' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

======================

As you can see a[3:] is not an integer  - what am I doing wrong?

Comment: oops, i forgot to add:      print '3a: ', len(a[3:]) #len works

Comment: `a[3:]` is not an int, but `a.size` is an int, do you maybe want `a[3:].size`?

Comment: that was it. 'a[3:].size' works just fine, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If you want the size of `a[3:]` then try:

```
>>> a[3:].size
5
```

By writing `a.size[3:]` what you are trying to do is `index` over an `integer` as `a.size` is an `integer`.